# Django: Losing my mind and pulling my hair out with Django auth

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm creating a SAAS as a project, and can't seem to wrap my dinosaur brain around this auth system. I started to roll my own system before I realized you could add on to the normal auth system. Is this completely wrong? Should I somehow extend the User model but still include all of my own attributes (username, password, etc)?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from annoying.fields import AutoOneToOneField
from myproject.core.modelfields import LowerAlphanumericField
from myproject.apps.account.models import Account

class Administrator(models.Model):
    """
    Administrator for an Account (application holds multiple accounts as it is a SAAS).
    """
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    username = LowerAlphanumericField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

If I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/auth/user/3/ I get an error, but the primary key for the third administrator object I created is 3 (which one would assume is the primary key for the related User object. Am I missing something. Also, do I need to create a password field, and all that junk here, or rather should I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seams to me that you don't really need to add that much extra information. Django auth covers all the aspects you are looking for:

- username
- password (sha1 hash)
- firstname
- lastname
- email

and Django auth also has a fairly useful permissions system:

- superuser
- staff
- active

Whenever I wish to add additional information to a User object, I generally create a new model and store a reference to the User.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Extra functionality
```

And then follow what @bste suggests, add `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'` to your settings file. This allows you to access a user profile (your extra information) with the `get_profile()` method on any `User` object.

Comment: @Marcus Is the superuser, staff, and active compatible with all custom views for an SAAS. I'm not letting my users have access to any admin pages.

Comment: @orokusaki making users not active is analogous to deleting a user. Staff users DO have access to the django admin, and superuser can do absolutely anything. Thus in your case I would use those attributes for developers of your project, and incorporate separate attributes into the UserProfile model to dictate actions specific to your system.

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of what I was looking for (the last bit about creating my own permission attributes). I didn't want to reinvent the wheel because every time I do I find out I didn't need to (it's either built-in and I missed it, or there's a huge project out there). In fact, I just finished building some pretty cool JSON-RPC stuff to extend some of the bits and pieces I found on the interwebs... Then I found Django Piston, which was a pleasant slap in the face.

Comment: @orokusaki Wow I did that exact same thing, I developed a small JSON returning API, but luckily, its so simplistic once I discovered Piston, I didn't feel I had wasted to much time, but we digress.

Answer (score 2):

are you already using built-in [django authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth)? if yes, then you can specify a model that's related to the User model in which you can store additional information about users.
it's explained here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

it's simple adding the following line:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.Adminstrator'
```

there's no need to store the passwrd yourself, i think django does this

Comment: @bste I'm trying to decide whether to use the built-in auth, and I'm leaning toward it since it's pretty full featured. My concern is this: How do I create a user object and give it all the attributes (username, password, etc) when creating my Administrator. I'm using AutoOneToOneField which I have no clue how it works. It seems to randomly select a User object to attach or something. I'm about to lose my mind :)

Comment: You need to register a handler for the signal django.db.models.signals.post_save  on the User model, and, in the handler, if created=True, create the associated user profile.